# How to create directory like structure in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I would like to create directory like structure in Wordpress. The best example you can see [here](http://wpplugins.com/plugin/164/paypal-file-download). So some products with additional information stored in custom fields (price, version and so on). Also I need links to be **SEO friendly**. Do you know about any tutorial or plugin that can handle this ?

Answer (score 1):

WordPress does this natively.

In the admin panel, go to Settings -> Permalinks and change the structure as desired. It has lots of instructions and links to help you.

Comment: Links are just a second part of the question. Main problem is, how to create directory structure in WP for custom products (e.g. books) ?

Comment: Check out Matt Wiebe's 'Smart Post Types' Code here:

http://somadesign.ca/projects/smarter-custom-post-types/

Answer (score 0):

You can read about [WordPress permalinks in the docs](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks).  They allow you to create custom formats for your URLs.

Comment: Links are just a second part of the question. Main problem is, how to create directory structure in WP for custom products (e.g. books) ?

Comment: Do you mean add a segment to the URL so that all "book" URLs would look like: www.yoursite.com/books/book-title?

Comment: Lets say I would like to create exactly the same as you can see on page I provided in my question.